# Borrar fichero en java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una agenda en java para la uni:) y no consigo que en una de las opciones que tengo de menu que sea borrar el data.txt se borré he intentado par de cosas que me han pasado y visto muchos tutoriales pero no lo consigo este ha sido el ultimo código intentado espero que me puedan ayudar

```
public void clearConsole() {

    File fichero = new File("data.txt");

    if (fichero.delete())
        System.out.println("El fichero ha sido borrado satisfactoriamente");
    else
        System.out.println("El fichero no pudó ser borrado");
}
```

Comment: @DavidCalderon no hay ningún método delete.

Comment: Si estás trabajando en Windows, creo que necesitas que el proceso esté ejecutándose con permisos de administrador. Adicional, sería bueno que revises que no tienes otro método que esté trabajando con el archivo directamente y que lo dejes abierto de casualidad.

Comment: El método `delete` existe. De lo contrario ¿Estás usando `java.io.File` o la clase `File` que usas pertenece a otro paquete? @DavidCalderon

Comment: ¿Qué error tienes? ¿La ruta "data.txt" es la correcta? Puedes poner en la salida la ruta completa con `fichero.getAbsolutePath()` para confirmar que el fichero está ahí.

Comment: ¿Nos puedes decir cuál es error que tienes con el código?
¿Te marca algún error cuándo ejecutas el código, no compila, o algo así?

Answer (score 3):

Ya han pasado 2 años desde que la pregunta fue planteado pero quiero aportar lo siguiente:
Si el fichero esta siendo utilizado por otro proceso como por ejemplo en un **`"FileInputStream"`** es necesario primero cerrarlo antes de tratar eliminarlo con el método "**`close()`**"
Ejemplo:

```
File imagen = new File("C:\\ejemplo.jpg");
FileInputStream readImage = new FileInputStream(imagen);
```

Si yo intento utilizar en este punto "**`imagen.delete()`**" no conseguiré nada ya que esta siendo utilizado por el **`InputStream`** por lo que es necesario:

```
readImage.close();
imagen.delete();
```

Esto deberia borrar correctamente el fichero.

Answer (score 2):

El código que utilizas está bien, probablemente tengas problemas con los privilegios o permisos. Prueba a hacerlo con permisos de administrador.

También es posible que tengas la ruta del archivo mal colocada.

Comment: En efecto, el código está bien. Y si te fijas no tiene ninguna ruta de archivo puesta. Yo añadiría a tu respuesta que el código como está va a borrar el archivo en el directorio actual, y le recomendaría modificarlo para incluir la ruta completa, pues el directorio actual puede variar dependiendo de muchas circunstacias. Pero bien, creo que has acertado.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [delete(Path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-), donde defines la ruta del archivo o directorio a eliminar.

```
try {
    Files.delete(path);
} catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
    System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
} catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
    System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
} catch (IOException x) {
    // File permission problems are caught here.
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

También puedes usar [deleteIfExists(Path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#deleteIfExists-java.nio.file.Path-), la diferencia es que este método también elimina el archivo, pero si el archivo no existe, no se produce ninguna excepción.

```
Files.deleteIfExists(path);
```

---

#### Aclaración:

Esto es lo que tiene el usuario (OP) lo cual es incorrecto, porque no existe el método [delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
 File fichero = new File("data.txt");
 fichero.delete();
```

pero en cambio existe el método [delete(Path path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-), el cual expongo en mi respuesta.

#### Realizo la aclaración con respecto a la persona que me dio puntuación negativa y agrego un comentario, seguramente no ha leído todo el thread ya que existe [delete(Path path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-).

Comment: OP está diciendo que fichero.delete no funciona (siendo fichero de clase File). Cambiar a java.nio.file.Files.delete no lo va a solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear esta función:

```
public static void eliminarFichero(File fichero) {

    if (!fichero.exists()) {
        System.out.println("El archivo data no existe.");
    } else {
        fichero.delete();
        System.out.println("El archivo data fue eliminado.");
    }

}
```

Y utilizarla despues

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File fichero = new File("RUTA_DEL_ARCHIVO");
    eliminarFichero(fichero);

}
```

Comment: OP está diciendo que `fichero.delete` no funciona...

Answer (score 0):

Eliminar un archivo en Java

Para borrar un archivo debemos invocar el método delete() de la clase File.

Ejemplo, eliminar el archivo “ejemplo1.txt”:

```
import java.io.File;


public class EliminarArchivo {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        try{

            File archivo = new File("C:\\carpeta1\\ejemplo1.txt");

            boolean estatus = archivo.delete();;

            if (!estatus) {

                System.out.println("Error no se ha podido eliminar el  archivo");

           }else{

                System.out.println("Se ha eliminado el archivo exitosamente");

           }

        }catch(Exception e){

           System.out.println(e);

        }

    }

}
```

http://blog.softmolina.com.mx/wp/2016/12/13/cambiar-de-nombre-mover-eliminar-o-copiar-un-archivo-en-java/

[Ver aqui](http://blog.softmolina.com.mx/wp/2016/12/13/cambiar-de-nombre-mover-eliminar-o-copiar-un-archivo-en-java/)